# query for detecting matched time/date

Tags: sql, ssms

I am trying to find out the match
time/date scheduled.

Comment: Please could you share the simple data and also the expected output as text not image ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Pls check above

Comment: Can you also add the expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

you have much duplicate data, but you can try applying window function

```
select *, case when start < lag(stop,1)
over(partition by id order by (select null))
then 'flag' end as test from entries;
```

[demo][1] here

Comment: What will happen if add the auto increment RowNo in table and then apply the above logic??

Comment: @SanuKumar not exactly sure what you mean, like add another auto incremented column?  you can always run sample code in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ey3ydjja)

Comment: an `auto_increment` row number would be your primary key, so you're saying you don't have a primary key in the data?  i don't think that will affect my solution

Comment: yes you are correct it has been same

Answer (score 0):

You have many Duplicate entries. Either you have to add a Trip date or remove those duplicate entries

Top Populate Overlap Entry, If you have proper data then try below query

```
SELECT  T1.ID,T1.TripNo,T1.Start,T1.Stop
FROM Trip T1 , Trip T2
WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID AND T2.TripNo = (T1.TripNo -1)
AND T1.Start < T2.Stop
```